# Printing each item from a list and its index, printing the index first then the item

Tags: python

Print each item in the list ["The Walking Dead", "Entourage", "The Sopranos", "The Vampire Diaries"] and its index.  Make sure to print its index first.  Then, print the movie name.

I am taking a python course in Udemy and this one of the tasks.  I keep getting an incorrect output.  I believe its because they want the output in a list.  This is the code I am inputing, but I am not sure how to get the output in a list.

```
x = ["The Walking Dead", "Entourage", "the sopranos", "The Vampire Diaries"]
index= 0
for i in x:
    print(index, i)
    index += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print output in a list, you can use a list comprehension:

```
x = ["The Walking Dead", "Entourage", "the sopranos", "The Vampire Diaries"]

[i for i in x]
```

To get the index and the name together in a list, you can also add `enumerate`

```
[i for i in enumerate(x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate`:

```py
x = ["The Walking Dead", "Entourage", "the sopranos", "The Vampire Diaries"]
for i,name in enumerate(x):
    print(f"{i}\t{name}")
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

> Return an enumerate object. iterable must be a sequence, an iterator,
> or some other object which supports iteration. The **next**() method
> of the iterator returned by enumerate() returns a tuple containing a
> count (from start which defaults to 0) and the values obtained from
> iterating over iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Store a tuple in the return list, let each of it's items contain ( index, name ) and instead of using index var try using range function.

Comment: Instead of describing it, please provide code.